# My ProgressBar won't show while loading my WebView, why?

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, android-webview, android-progressbar

I have created a `WebViewActivity` extending `Activity` and showing a `WebView` inside of my app instead of redirecting to the browser.

So I tried to use `AsyncTask` to show my `ProgressBar` while the view is loading. But the progress bar doesn't display at all. Here is the code I'm using:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webView;
    TextView textView;
    ProgressBar bar;

    private class Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            String url = new String(getIntent().getStringExtra("url"));
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            textView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("title"));
            bar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

        vueText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.barTitle);
        vueWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        bar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        new Async().execute();
    }
}
```

And here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/grayBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/barTitle" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sc1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/barTitle"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/WebView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you add the entire xml layout

Comment: @jimmithy Yes I just did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perform the background action (loading the URL) of the `AsyncTask` in the `doInBackground()` method.

The `onPostExecute()` is invoked on the UI thread so it will freeze the UI while running.

See the documentation of [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more details.

Comment: Excuse me, is that the picture of Nicolas Cage?

Comment: =) No that is me in the picture, but I can see the resemblance to mister Cage now that you mention it.

Comment: Thanks  :-)  (I'm just a fan of him)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `pubishProgress()` inside the `doInBackground`.

Then override onProgressUpdate

Comment: Edit to `publishProgress()`

Comment: publishProgress() is only if you want to react on partial progress. For example if you have a linear progress-bar that you want to represent how much work is left.